# How to assert no other methods are invoked on a Unitils Mock

Tags: mocking, unitils

I am aware of `MockUnitils.assertNoMoreInvocations();`, but how to achieve a similar effect only for one Mock object?

I am doing kind-of black box testing on some methods. I know a list of methods they *may* call on the mocks, but what I have to make sure is they absolutely won't call the other methods.

It seems I'll need something like `assertOptionallyInvoked()` or `assertNoOtherInovations()` on the mocks. Is this possible with Unitils?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by implementing my own Scenario class.